# BIND as a Private Network DNS Server - Getting REFUSED

Tags: named, bind9

I've setup named to act as a local dynamic dns server on my private network with dhcpd. All is working.

The only thing that bugs me is that I'm getting REFUSED when querying hostname that doesn't exist when I should get NXDOMAIN.

For example:

```
host -t a ns
ns.domain.local has address 192.168.1.225

host -t a ns1
Host ns1 not found: 5(REFUSED)
```

My `/etc/named.conf` has `recursion no;`

When I'm querying for not-existing FQDN record, I actually get proper NXDOMAIN response.

```
host -t a ns1.domain.local
Host ns1.domain.local not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Using `tcpdump` I can track the following behavior:

```
17:22:04.602686 IP localhost.33281 > localhost.domain: 29032+ A? ns1.domain.local. (31)
17:22:04.602895 IP localhost.domain > localhost.33281: 29032 NXDomain*- 0/1/0 (75)
17:22:04.603198 IP localhost.60655 > localhost.domain: 49935+ A? ns1. (21)
17:22:04.603270 IP localhost.domain > localhost.60655: 49935 Refused- 0/0/0 (21)
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf` has search `search domain.local` so it tries first and reports NXDOMAIN which is fine but then goes for **ns1.** and REFUSED.

What am I missing?

Comment: Turn up the debug logging on `named`, then tell us what its complaints are.

Comment: To look up `ns1.` (note the dot) it has to recurse, and you've turned that of, so it returns `REFUSED`. The problem is not with `bind` but with the client (`dig`) that's using a search list that includes `.`.

Comment: @wurtel make that an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look up `ns1.` (note the dot) `bind` (actually the `named` process) has to recurse, and you've turned that off; hence it returns REFUSED.

The problem is not with `bind` but with the client (`dig`) that's using a search list that includes `.`.

Comment: Thanks, by adding `options ndots:0` to my `/etc/resolv.conf` I get the expected behavior!